# I want change the small check-box beside to item color in checkedlistbox in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want change the small check-box color beside to item color in checklist in c#

[image]

```
public ColorControl()
    {
        KnownColor[] colors = Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor)) as KnownColor[];
        foreach (var item in colors)
        {
            this.Items.Add(item.ToString());
        }
    }
    protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Color ItemColor = Color.FromName(this.Items[e.Index].ToString());

        e.Graphics.DrawString(this.Items[e.Index].ToString(),this.Font,new SolidBrush(ItemColor) ,e.Bounds);

        base.OnDrawItem(e);}
```

Comment: Have you tried _anything_? Show us what you tried. We are happy to help you but we are not going to write the code for you.

Comment: look like you use Paint to draw this, not the screenshot.

Comment: public ColorControl()
        {
            KnownColor[] colors = Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor)) as KnownColor[];
            foreach (var item in colors)
            {
                this.Items.Add(item.ToString());
            }
        }
        protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            Color ItemColor = Color.FromName(this.Items[e.Index].ToString());
           
            e.Graphics.DrawString(this.Items[e.Index].ToString(),this.Font,new SolidBrush(ItemColor) ,e.Bounds);
            
            base.OnDrawItem(e);
        }

Comment: Winform @DarshanPatel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is worthy of an answer but here is a shot. 
As is mentioned in the answer by Cody Grey The checkbox is not really simple to override. Another alternative besides making your own class inheriting from `CheckListBox` is to make your own control inheriting from `Control`. You can use buttons with changing background colors for the checkboxes. And add whatever other features you want.

Something like

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;
namespace CustomButton
{
    public partial class NeatButton : Control
    {
        //Some globals
        private bool _Pressed = false;
        private bool _Activated = false;

        //you will want to put your code for clicking checkboxes in the Mouse overrides. The OnPaint override is where you decide how the boxes look.
        protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e){...}
        protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e){...}
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe){...}

        //You will want some propeties
     public new string Text
    {
        get { return base.Text; }
        set
        {
            if (value == base.Text)
                return;
            base.Text = value;

            Invalidate(); //Keeps text showing changes in real time
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Works with Pressed to determine if the button should do something  when clicked. **Use a property like this for the checkboxes**
    /// </summary>
    private bool Activated
    {
        get { return _Activated; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _Activated)
                return;
            _Activated = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Works with Activated to determine if the button should do something when clicked 
    /// </summary>
    private bool Pressed
    {
        get { return _Pressed; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _Pressed)
                return;

            _Pressed = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }
```

While this is not a complete example it should show a very basic set up for a custom control.

Once the custom control is working then want to build it and grab the exe from where ever you built it. Then in the form you want to use it in you drop the exe in to the project folder. Then in the solution explorer right click on References and then `Add reference`. Then browes to your exe and check it off and click 'OK'. Save your project and open up the form designer. Right click on the ToolBox and click `Choose Items`. Find your exe and check it off and hit ok. The Checkbox you made should now appear in the tool box and can be dragged and dropped onto a form and used like any other control.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The checkbox is drawn by the operating system. It is intentionally designed so that it looks like every other checkbox on the screen. This massively helps with usability. Users will not know what they can click on a red box and use it like a checkbox.

If you insist on making your application difficult to use, you will have to owner-draw the control. It will not be easy, `CheckedListBox` is not designed to support owner-drawing. The `DrawItem` event is documented as being "not relevant to this class." The control is already owner-drawn by the framework.

At the very least, you will need to create a new class that inherits from `CheckedListBox` so that you can override the `OnDrawItem` method.

```
public class ColorCheckBoxListBox : CheckedListBox
{
    protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: i already do that    public ColorControl()
        {
            KnownColor[] colors = Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor)) as KnownColor[];
            foreach (var item in colors)
            {
                this.Items.Add(item.ToString());
            }
        }
        protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            Color ItemColor = Color.FromName(this.Items[e.Index].ToString());
           
            e.Graphics.DrawString(this.Items[e.Index].ToString(),this.Font,new SolidBrush(ItemColor) ,e.Bounds);
            
            base.OnDrawItem(e);
        }

Comment: If you put the code you have in the question, then not only will be people be able to see it *before* they answer, but it will even be formatted correctly so that it is readable.